# How to cancel the chrome camera permission bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a dynamically created html5 camera video popup that works fine.  The problem is if I cancel it without answering the chrome camera permission request bar, it destroys the html fine but the permission bar stays.  The camera is stopped and the light is off but only refreshing the page will kill the permission bar.

```
var webcam=function()
  {
  var cam=document.createElement("canvas"),vid=document.createElement("video"),S=null;
  vid.autoplay=true;
  cam.width=640;
  cam.height=480;
  navigator.getUserMedia({video: {optional: [{minWidth:640},{minWidth:480},{minWidth:360}]}},function(stream){vid.src=(window.URL||window.mozURL||window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(stream);S=stream},function(error){console.log("error")});
  webcam.stop=function(){if(S)S.stop();vid.src=""};
  var dv=document.createElement("div");
  dv.appendChild(vid);
  return dv;
  }
```

If I cancel it by running **webcam.stop** and removing the relevant html it turns off the camera, and removes the video.  Works fine if I have already answered the browser permission request.  But in chrome, the permission request stays until a page refresh.

Is there any way to programmatically remove the browser permission bar or cancel it?  In firefox for example the permission request disappears when the video does.

UPDATE
Created a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/CM5Tk/7/

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle?  It sounds like you're running into a Chrome bug related to redrawing the page.  However, I don't have this issues with Chrome in my applications.

Comment: Yes, see update above.  If you hit the stop button without answering the chrome permission request, the latter stays.

Comment: Great question. +1. I don't think there's a way. Maybe file a ticket? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @poby I can't reproduce the problem with your jsFiddle.  Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57 (Official Build 235101) m on Windows.

Comment: I have the same chrome version.  To reproduce the issue, run the jsfiddle, ignore the browser permission request, click stop.  The video html is removed but the permission request bar remains.